# select SQL Query without same info on a field

Tags: sql, select, group-by, distinct

I have a table and I want to select some rows on this table with no duplicate on some column.
for example I have a table like this

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| player_Id | player_Name | league| Description  |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

some records for example :

```
1,Messi     ,la liga        , he is a good player in la liga

2,ronaldo   ,la liga        , he is a good player in la liga

3,roney     ,premier league , very good player

4,casias    ,la liga,       ,goalkeeper
```

now I want to select from this table

```
select * from table where league= 'la liga'
```

but I want to select only thos with different Description  this mean I want the query only return messi or Ronaldo(because of same Description) + casias

how can I do this ?
whats the best solution and what do you suggest ?

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: Which one do you want to return from player_id and player_name? or randomly for distinct description values??

Answer (score 0):

Use [**GROUP BY**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html) clause to find distinct description in query.

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA 
WHERE league= 'la liga'
GROUP BY Description;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but if you are using `SQL Server` or `Oracle` you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` function like

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Description ORDER BY Description) AS rn
FROM players
) tab
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some solutions :

```
SELECT Max(player_Name) [player_Name],
       league,
       Description
FROM   @yourtable
WHERE  league = 'la liga'
GROUP  BY league,Description
```

Note : above solution will not return `player_Id` but will work in almost all RDBMS systems. if `player_Id` is not very much concerned then use this.

or you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` function to filter only one player of multiples having same `description` and `league` but it is support by MS SQL Server/Oracle/Postgresql (not supported by MySQL). For example :

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER()
                 OVER(
                   partition BY description
                   ORDER BY player_Id DESC) rn
        FROM   @yourtable
        WHERE  league = 'la liga') t
WHERE  rn = 1
```

OR if you want similar result for all `league` then use below (just remove this condition : `league = 'la liga'` )

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER()
                 OVER(
                   partition BY league, description
                   ORDER BY player_Id DESC) rn
        FROM   @yourtable) t
WHERE  league = 'la liga'
       AND rn = 1
```

OR You may try `left join`/`not exists` like this :

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   @yourtable a
       LEFT JOIN @yourtable b
              ON a.league = b.league
                 AND a.Description = b.Description
                 AND a.player_Id < b.player_Id
WHERE  b.player_Id IS NULL
       AND a.league = 'la liga' 

SELECT a.*
FROM   @yourtable a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   @yourtable b
                   WHERE  a.league = b.league
                          AND a.Description = b.Description
                          AND a.player_Id < b.player_Id)
       AND a.league = 'la liga'
```

Comment: is partitioning over a varchar column right? I think its too slow for a big table that have about 5 million rows ?! Any faster solution exists?

Comment: well you can try `exists` OR `left join` like : `select distinct a.* from @yourtable a
left join @yourtable b
on a.league = b.league and a.Description = b.Description and a.player_Id < b.player_Id
where b.player_Id is null and a.league = 'la liga'`. but it seems, it won't help either due to number of records and performance aspect.